# Cannot login into my user account Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, session

I cannot login into my user account. The password is correct, actually it's stuck in a login loop, i mean it returns to the login window after i type the password. I've tried many things to fix the trouble without success.

But here is the catch, I am able to connect to the same home directory with a new user account which I created in the terminal mode. Still, it's impossible to log in the account i usually use.
So what do you think?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1175274/edit) your question to accurately describe what happens when you login. An error message? A refusal message? Flashing? Nothing? Freezes? Something Else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I've read many solutions about login loop, but no one could solve my problem

Comment: @Linuxian The term "many" is very much vague. Can you please mention what exactly have you tried so far?